Does OLS give the maximum likelihood estimation for a linear log model?
I'm fitting a model $y=a\times \log(x)+ b$ using standard scikit linear regression (wich uses OLS) and a transformation $x'=\log(x)$. My doubt is: the parameters  I get for the model are the best one if I assume, for example, that my errors are normally distributed? I know that OLS will give the maximum likelihood estimator for the $x'$ but I have doubts if that is true for $x$. I would appreciate any references on the subject too.

Are you ever using just the $x$ alone?

Hi, from the business perspective my problem has a logarithm like curve ( involves saturation). That's why we need to use log(x).

Then how does $x$ get involved with the maximum likelihood issue? (You seem to know the equivalence between minimizing square loss and maximizing Gaussian likelihood.)

A transformation of your independent variable $x$ does not affect the distribution of the dependent variable $y$ (or the error, by extension). Given your stated model setup, which goes by many names ("linear-log", "level-log", "semi-log", etc.), $\hat{a}_{OLS}$ is still the maximum likelihood estimate.
As for references, have a look at chapter 5.4 in Gujarati or chapter 4.2 in Dougherty.
